# Get last documents with a distinct criteria

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

### Situation

I'm having trouble coming up with a good way to do a certain MongoDb query. First, here's what kind of query I want to do. Assume a simple database which logs entry and exit events (and possibly other actions, doesn't matter) by electronic card swipe. So there's a collection called `swipelog` with simple documents which look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("524ab4790a4c0e402200052c")
    name: "John Doe", 
    action: "entry",
    timestamp: ISODate("2013-10-01T1:32:12.112Z") 
}
```

Now I want to list names and their last entry times (and any other fields I may want, but example below uses just these two fields).

### Current solution

Here is what I have now, as a "one-liner" for MongoDb JavaScript console:

```
db.swipelog.distinct('name')
           .forEach( function(name) {

    db.swipelog.find( { name: name, action:"entry" } )
               .sort( { $natural:-1 } )
               .limit(1)
               .forEach( function(entry) {

        printjson( [ entry.name, entry.timestamp ] )
    }) 
})
```

Which prints something like:

```
[ "John Doe", ISODate("2013-10-01T1:32:12.112Z")]
[ "Jane Deo", ISODate("2013-10-01T1:36:12.112Z")]
...
```

### Question

I think above has the obvious scaling problem. If there are a hundred names, then 1+100 queries will be made to the database. So what is a good/correct way to get "last `timestamp` of every distinct `name`" ? Changing database structure or adding some collections is ok, if it makes this easier.

Comment: ...and before someone points it out, yes, `name` is a poor way to identify people, but this is just example code. If it bothers you, assume that new people with identical names must change their name before getting a card ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use aggregation framework to achieve this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
          [
             {$match:
                  {action:'entry'}
             },
             {$group:
                  {_id:'$name',
                   first:
                         {$max:'$timestamp'}
                  }
             }
          ])
```

If you likely to include other fields in the results, you can use the [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/first/) operator

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
          [
             {$match:
                  {action:'entry'}
             },
             {$sort:
                  {name:1, timestamp:-1}
             },
             {$group:
                  {_id:'$name',
                   timestamp: {$first:'$timestamp'},
                   otherField: {$first:'$otherField'},
                  }
             }
          ])
```

Comment: Seems to work! But how to add more fields from the *same* document, where `$timestamp` is taken from? Only way my MongoDb novice brain can think of, is get the `$_id`'s of wanted documents like this, then do a 2nd query to get this set of documents (still much better than what I have in my question, of course).

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution for your problem in case if you likely to include additional fields.

Comment: Ah, that way! The 2nd version is exactly what I am after, and I learned quite a bit about how to use `aggregate`. Thanks!

Comment: One more question about 2nd piece of code: why sorting by both `name` and `timestamp`? Like, is it just for having names sorted in case I want them sorted, or does it improve performance, or is it actually required for getting correct result?

Comment: This is for getting the correct results , as my understsanding, probably enough to sort for the dates (probably group does the rest), i have not tested this part.

Comment: In an other question some others tested out that the sorting for timestamp is enough, in my opinion sorting this way is not slower and maybe fast up the group phase (depend on the implementation). Many-Many thanks for the bounty, i am glad that could help.

Comment: Hi @attish: Will the group by maintain initial sorting order?

Answer (score 3):

*This answer should be a comment on attish's answer above, but I don't have sufficient rep here to comment*

Keep in mind that the aggregation framework [cannot return more than 16MB of data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). If you have a very large number of users, you may run into this limitation on your production system.

[MongoDB 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/) adds new features to the aggregation framework to deal with this:

- `db.collection.aggregateCursor()` (temporary name) is identical to `db.collection.aggregate()` except that it returns a cursor instead of a document. This avoids the 16MB limitation
- `$out` is a new pipeline phase that directs the pipeline's output to a collection. This allows you to run aggregation jobs
- `$sort` has been improved to remove its [RAM limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Aggregation%20Sort%20Operation) and increase speed

If query performance is more important than data age, you could schedule a regular `aggregate` command that stores its results in collection like `db.last_swipe`, then have your application simply query `db.last_swipe` for the relevant user.

Conclusion: I agree that attish has the right approach. However, you may run into trouble scaling it on the current MongoDB release and should look into Mongo 2.6.