# mongodb aggregate framework query with max date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have few records like this

```
userid purchased  brand
1      2012-1-21  honda
1      2013-1-1   toyota
1      2013-2-30  mercedez

2      2013-1-1   honda
2      2012-1-1   toyota
2      2013-12-13 mercedez
```

I want to get the user record with max purchased date. like following

```
1      2013-2-30  mercedez
2      2013-12-13 mercedez
```

I m trying to user mongodb aggregate frame work but having problem with the correct query.

```
db.carsrecord.aggregate([{"$match" :{"userid":{"$in":[1,2,3,11]}}} ,
    {"$group":{"_id": {"uid":"$userid"},timecreated:{"$max":"$purchased" }}} ])
```

it returns me correct hid and with time but not returning the car brand.

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "uid" : 1
        },
        "timecreated" : ISODate("2013-10-03T20:01:45.366Z")
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use $first operator, check this question and my answer for the explanation: [Get last documents with a distinct criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114541/get-last-documents-with-a-distinct-criteria/19117357#19117357)

the right code will be:

```
db.carsrecord.aggregate(
      [{"$match" :{"userid":{"$in":[1,2,3,11]}}} , 
       {"$sort": {userid:1, purchased:-1}},
       {"$group":{"_id": 
                     {     "uid":"$userid"  },
                  "timecreated":{"$first":"$purchased" },
                  "brand":{"$first":"$brand"}}} 
      ])
```

Comment: Is it possible to format output also. at the moment out put is like this {
   "_id" : {
    "uid" : 1
   },
   "timecreated" : ISODate("2013-10-03T20:01:45.366Z"),
   "brand" : toyota
  }. instead i like to get {uid:1 , timecreated:2013,brand:"toyota"}

Comment: You can run an additional $project phase... Something like : $project:{uid:'$_id.uid',timecreate:{$year:'$timecreated'},brand:1,_id:0} To extract the year you can use this (i hope i used the right syntax will test later): http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-nav/#date-operators

Comment: Y u user sort on userid ? i just checked it work fine without that too.

Comment: Yes maybe you are right while group will does it anyway on the next step. It is not neccessary but maybe useful for performance. It would be great to know the exact implementation, to answer this question in a correct way. But your point is good on this, that have poped up in the other question too.

Comment: So basically you have to list every field you want in the `$group` section?