# Distinct by a key and then get results of fields other than the key

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given that I have the following in MongoDB:

```
[{_id: 1, key: A, someData: 'abc'},
{_id: 2, key: B, someData: 'def'},
{_id: 3, key: A, someData: 'ghi'},
{_id: 4, key: C, someData: 'jkl'},
{_id: 5, key: C, someData: 'mno'}]
```

How should I write my mongoDB query in order to return distinct-ed results WITH some additional fields?

The expected results should be:

```
[{key: A, someData: 'ghi'},
{key: B, someData: 'def'},
{key: C, someData: 'mno'}]
```

Note that the above results will return the latest record for each distinct key (eg for key = 'A', record of _id = 3 is the latest as compared to _id = 1).

Appreciate some help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.aggregate()` which specifically has [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) as an accumulator for [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },           // Sorting by order for "latest"
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$key",
    "someData": { "$last": "$someData" }
  }}
])
```

Typically you would use [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) when you require a specific order since, "last" implies you want a specific order and where something is within the grouping boundary is therefore important.

Also note that [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) means something quite different to [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/), where the former is dependant on the "order" which is typically "sorted" as mentioned. The [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator on the other hand simply takes the "largest" from anywhere within the grouping boundary.

Typically if you want more than one property returned other than the grouping key, you actually mean [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use db.collection.distinct(fields,query)

```
db.collection.distinct('key')
```

Comment: But how do I return fields other than distinct key for each distinct-ed record?

Comment: maybe it might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114541/get-last-documents-with-a-distinct-criteria

Comment: @oatcrunch They actually don't know and simply saw "distinct" in your question title and then copied the first answer they found. Hence why just commenting with links.